# Fastest way to obtain limit of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions

I'm tasked to find the limit of such a function:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \tan(x)} - \sqrt{1 + \sin(x)}}{x^3}$

My immediate instinct is to use L'Hospital's Rule to differentiate the numerator and denominator, and rinse and repeat until the denominator no longer contained $x$, which I did to arrive at an answer of $0$, but boy was the process extremely tedious and painful.

However, this process was way too painful. My other instinctive thought was to rationalise the function to obtain $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(x) - \sin(x)}{x^3\bigl(\sqrt{1 + \tan(x)} + \sqrt{1 + \sin(x)}\bigr)}$ but this not only does not remove $x$ from the denominator, I have to apply the product rule which will no doubt complicate the process further.

Can someone advise how else I can go about solving this more efficiently?

Comment: Fastest? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%28sqrt%281%2Btan%28x%29%29+-+sqrt%281%2Bsin%28x%29%29%29+%2F+x%5E3+when+x+-%3E+0 ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Picking from your second approach,
$$\tan x-\sin x=\frac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{\cos x}=\frac{2\sin^2(\frac x2)\sin x}{\cos x}$$

Now use the fact $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}t=1$.

The answer is ***NOT*** $0$.

---

**Edit:** Using the above substitution you get$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2}{\cos x(\sqrt{1+\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x})}\cdot\frac{\sin^2(\frac x2)\sin x}{x^3}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2}{\cos x(\sqrt{1+\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x})}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(\frac x2)\sin x}{x^3}$$
The first limit evaluates to $1$. Write the second limit as$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{2t}\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{2t}$$where $t=x/2\to0$. This evaluates to $1/4$.
[image: Graph]

Comment: At first glance I am slightly mind-boggled. Allow me a little time to digest this! And thank you for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: Sure, take your time. I'm here if you need clarification. I made use of the trigonometric identity: $\cos x=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, perhaps I'm getting a brain freeze and still cannot comprehend the purpose of the steps you just introduced. The denominator I am getting is $x^3 (\sqrt{1+tan(x)} + \sqrt{1+sin(x)})$. It seems to complicated things more than it's helping because the $x^3$ is still there. Perhaps I'm missing a particular technique?

Comment: @a9302c See the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never would have thought of doing this. I guess my concept/mindset is still stuck at the lower level of only being to see the whole fraction together, and not yet of being able to split them up tactically. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

L'Hospital's rule is not the alpha and omega of limits computation!
From the second approach, you can use Taylor's formula at order $3$ and equivalence of functions:
$$\tan x-\sin x=x+\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)-\Bigl(x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^3)\Bigr)=\frac{x^3}2+o(x^3),$$
whence $\;\tan x-\sin x\sim_0\dfrac{x^3}2$.

On the other hand, $\sqrt{1 + \tan(x)} + \sqrt{1 + \sin(x)}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}2$ , so we have
$$\frac{\tan(x) - \sin(x)}{x^3\bigl(\sqrt{1 + \tan(x)} + \sqrt{1 + \sin(x)}\bigr)}\sim_0 \frac{\frac12\, x^3}{x^3\cdot 2}=\frac14.$$

Comment: Hi Bernard ! I fixed a small typo in the last line. By the way, I am always surprised by the fact that many people do not see that L'Hospital's rule is embedded in Taylor expansion. Cheers and take care.

Comment: Hi Claude! Thank you for the edit. I wondered what typo it was, and discovered the denominator of the coefficient had overflown into the exponent. I definitely should reread myself before posting!

Comment: Do you really think that you are the only one ? If this was the case, welcome to the club !